# Determine the knot projection with smallest number of bridges

Tags: knot-theory

I have been reading about knot theory for some time, and I am constantly struggling to find the bridge number given a knot or even find the knot projection after searching up the bridge number from databases. I am wondering if there are tricks to find the knot projection that presents the knot with the least number of bridges?

Comment: What's your version of bridge number? Is it the number of bridges in a diagram, or the version where you have a braid closed with caps on the top and cups on the bottom? I find the second version easier when it comes to finding a diagram with minimal bridge number.

Comment: @KyleMiller just the number of bridges. or can you explain how to do the second version? I have seen it somewhere before

Comment: I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462453/bridge-presentation-of-a-knot) which mentions it. This is the point of view where it's clearer that 2-bridge knots correspond to rational knots.

Comment: Also, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158599/given-a-knot-whats-the-minimal-genus-of-a-torus-the-knot-is-embeddable-on/3159806#3159806) you can see how a 2-bridge knot from the second point of view has much fewer crossings than from the first.